# Django: In templates using an if statement inside a for loop of _set.all doesn't work. why?

Tags: django, django-models

If you have a better way to reformulate my question please let me know. My template is as follows:

```
{% for x in group.groupmember_set.all %}

  {% if x.user != user.username %}

    {{ x.user }}

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This statement prints all users in the Group, as though the if statement doesn't exist. If I remove the if statement, eventually prints the same and makes sense... **I want to filter out** `user.username` with an if statement but doesn't work. What is wrong? Group has a ManytoMany relation with User through GroupMember.
My `models.py` file reads:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through="GroupMember")

class GroupMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and in `views.py` I use `DetailView`, e.g.,

```
class SingleGroup(DetailView):
    model = Group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't set `user` variable in template nor passed it in view's context, then you should use `request.user`. Change it like that:

```
{% for x in group.groupmember_set.all %}

  {% if x.user != request.user %}

    {{ x.user }}

  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Another thing is you should compare object of the same type, ie. `User` object to `User` object or `username` string to `username` string - definitely not `User` object to `username` string.

Comment: thanks for adding additional comments for general understanding